# Postgres: is there any row_to_json equivalent that returns values only?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, copy

In a project I'm working on, I need to stream potentially large data sets from a Postgres database to the client, for analytics purposes.

The application is built in Rails (irrelevant for this question) and after a bit of research I'm currently able to stream query results by using `COPY` in Postgres:

```
COPY (SELECT row_to_json(t) from (#{query}) t) TO STDOUT;
```

Sources (for who's interested):

https://shift.infinite.red/fast-csv-report-generation-with-postgres-in-rails-d444d9b915ab

https://github.com/brianhempel/stream_json_demo

This works, but it yields every row as a key-value pair, e.g.:

```
["{\"id\":403457,\"email\":\"email403457@example.com\",\"first_name\":\"Firstname403457\",\"last_name\":\"Lastname403457\",\"source\":\"adwords\",\"created_at\":\"2015-08-05T22:43:07.295796\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-01-19T04:48:29.464051\"}"]
```

In the spirit of minimising the size (in bytes) of the response and especially since this is getting served through the web, I want to return just an array of values for every row, i.e.:

```
["[403457, \"email403457@example.com\", \"Firstname403457\", \"Lastname403457\", \"adwords\", \"2015-08-05T22:43:07.295796\", \"2017-01-19T04:48:29.464051\"]"]
```

Is there a way to achieve this within Postgres, even by nesting functions, starting from the query above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple SQL function that converts a row into the desired format:

```
CREATE FUNCTION row2json(anyelement) RETURNS json
   LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS
'SELECT json_agg(z.value) FROM json_each(row_to_json($1)) z';
```

Then you use that to transform the output:

```
SELECT row2json(mytab) FROM mytab;
```

If performance is more important than JSON output, just cast the result to a string:

```
SELECT CAST(mytab AS text) FROM mytab;
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. This approach works but by using an aggregate function I lose the streaming capability. I.e. Postgres serves the entire result block back instead of giving rows one by one, which is what happens in the example I gave.

Comment: True. I have changed the answer to fit the bill.

Comment: You are the man @laurenz-albe :). Accepting and upvoting. Now back to the real world, I will have to see whether to actually go with this as the performance loss is significant (3x as slow as the key-value pair starting point). Do you see any room for optimisation in the function you posted or is this truly the only way?

Comment: If performance is the issue, cast to `text`. I have addded a description to the answer.

Comment: Yes. Actually this would work better in this sense: `COPY (SELECT * FROM mytab) TO STDOUT (FORMAT CSV, FORCE_QUOTE *)`. The drawback is that everything is enclosed in double quotes, making me lose visibility on data types. But it still allows to output a set of strings that can be served as valid JSON. Every solution seems to be having its own pros and cons, I'd love to see some performant way of obtaining a typed array of values within PG.

Comment: If all fails, write a C function that formats your data. Cumbersome, but the fastest option.